# Backbone boilerplate - how to change template directory?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When I specify a template for a View in my Module, the URL that gets formed is: /app/templates/template.html. I have all of the boilerplate code inside of a static folder, so I need the URL to look like /static/app/templates/template.html. How can I change the configuration to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is right but I know Backbone-boilerplate uses require.js so I'd suggest putting

`baseUrl: 'static'`

in your config.js file

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to change any of the template path dirs, which leads me to believe that the templates are loaded separate from the requirejs config.

Comment: You could be right.  Do your template paths start with "/"?  if so try beginning without it as that should make it relative.  (just shooting in the dark tbh)

Comment: They do not. The templates seem to be relative to /app rather than /static/app.